# Realm object fields get nil when there is Date object

Tags: swift, realm

When I try to put a Date object, then all the fields get nil. I mean name and id and anything else I put there.

```
class Transaction: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable, Decodable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: UUID
    @Persisted var name: String?
    @Persisted var start: Date?
    @Persisted var stop: Date?
}
```

This gives me an empty Results object.

```
class Transaction: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable, Decodable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: UUID
    @Persisted var name: String?
    @Persisted var start: String?
    @Persisted var stop: String?
}
```

This works.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably the Date that you are trying to read doesn't conform to Date type and the read fails

Comment: @George but then shouldn't the date field be nil only? In my case all the fields becomes nil

Comment: Realm's documentation explicitly calls out that List<T> properties should be declared using let rather than var to avoid this problem. Change from var to let

Comment: @George can't do let on a property wrapper. I dont have lists

Answer (score 0):

Date objects are fully supported in Realm, as show here [Supported Types](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/data-types/supported-property-types/) but you've defined them as optionals with no initializer so... they are nil

If you want them to be populated by default when the object is created just do this

```
@Persisted var stop = Date()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had to use decoder with custom datestrategy. To me what I can't put my head around is that even when an optional date field is nil then everything else become nil for some reason although there should be data

Comment: Well I see the confusion. I am not asking why date is nil. I get the data from an api endpoint and when I swap the date? to string? I get the id, name, start and stop fields populated. However, when I set start and stop fields back to date?, the existing ones disappear upon sync and everything gets nilled. What I was hoping to see was, lets say my date formatter is wrong and produces nil, even then I should get the id, if exists name then start=nil and stop=nil. Instead I get nil on every field.

Comment: @Qoarth Can you clarify what *swap the date? to string?,  *when I set start and stop fields back to date?, the existing ones disappear*? means? Also, what does "everything gets nilled" mean? Sync'ing will not alter an objects structure, ever, it will only update changed values - nothing will ever be nilled unless you nil it. Perhaps you can update your question with more details and some sample code of what you're doing.  I will then update my answer once it's more clear. Oh - when responding to users here on SO, precede their name with an at sign, like @ Jay (no space)

Comment: @Jey
imagine you get the following response:
[{
id: (some UUID)
name: "someString"
start: "someDateString"
stop: "someDateString"
},
{
id: (some UUID)
name: "someString"
start: "someDateString"
stop: null
},
...]

decoding this into a realm object works when the start and stop fields are of type String? however, when start and stop are of type Date? all the fields of Transaction becomes nil as in id = nil, name = nil, start = nil, stop = nil.

My expectation would be id = (some UUID), name = "someString", start = someDatefromString, stop = someDatefromString

Comment: @Qoarth ok, can you update the question with that comment and then include the code you're using to decode that into a realm object? Please include a sample of the exact data you are encoding into the realm object as well. My guess is, that data is causing it to fail but we need to see it and how it's being done.